# Pure functions vs object oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript

After reading [this article regarding pure functions](http://alistapart.com/article/making-your-javascript-pure) it seems to me that when working when object oriented JavaScript the concept of pure functions doesn't seem to be as simple to implement unless you want to end up calling functions with plenty of arguments or with an array of them.

Lets say I have the following function within a Javascript object.

```
function demo() {
    var self = this;

    //fixed in some other method
    self.order.owner = null;
    self.selectedEvent() = null;
    self.order.booking_id = null;
    self.order.order_id = null;
    self.details = null;
    self.notification = null;
    self.notifyDesk = null;
    self.additionalText = null;

    //WILL THIS FUNCTION BE PURE? 
    self.test = function() {
        if (self.order.owner && self.selectedEvent()) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(self.order.booking_id == '4000' || !self.isValid(self.order.order_id) ){
            return false;
        }
        return self.whatever;
    };

    return self;
}

var myDemo = new Demo();

//whatever other actions over the demo object here

console.log( myDemo.test() );
```

The method `addOrder` It is making use of 5 variables outside the function scope and belonging to the object scope. 
That's not what I understood to be a "pure" function, but unless we want to call `addOrder` with 5 parameters, or a single array parameter with 5 elements, it doesn't seem to me we can get a pure Javascript function out of it.

This happens quite often in OO Javascript and accessing the object properties is something pretty common ?

What am I missing? Please delight me!

Comment: I think the major thing is that you are confusing this _constructor_ with _functions_ - they are actually very different. If you just call `demo()` your `self` or `this` would be `window`, so it uses global and would not be pure, but when called with `new` it creates it's own `this` object which will act as a locally declared variable, so now your 'function' is technically pure, but the result is not an outcome, it's an `object` (which is a predictable outcome, but it's not the same as a function per se).

Comment: I'm talking about the function `addOrder`, which depends on the Demo object and any previous method modifying any of its properties. Therefore the value of addOrders itself won't be predictable unless provided with the object state.

Comment: @Alvaro Just to clarify, your `addOrder` function is fine but if you want a pure function, you should make `addOrder` a standalone function which takes a `demo` object as a parameter and uses that parameter instead of `self`.

Comment: But `addOther` exists nowhere else than _on_ the object, so let me clarify a bit: you are not really confusing the constructor and functions, it's the difference between a _method_ and a function. The article you posted was talking about pure functions, but if you continue this line of thinking into methods, then methods _need_ an object, but should not manipulate any data outside of it. By that rule, you can speak of _pure methods_, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @somethinghere yep, the example I used is not really a good one, as it is a method as you pointed out. I'll think about a better example.

Comment: I think @MikeC is probably closest to the solution. If you want pure functions _and_ some sort of object orientation, then you should have methods that take objects as parameters to make sure they are pure. However, Object Oriented becomes sort of meaningless if your objects don't have methods, then you get in trouble, for example, if you ever wanted to switch from drawing a square to a circle, you would have to change the pure function called, instead of just switching out the object... Just a thought.

Comment: @Alvaro In response to your edit, no. That function is not pure. It relies on external state (`self`). A pure function takes in input and always produces the same output. That function takes no input, it relies on mutable state, which is the antithesis to pure functions.

Comment: @MikeC exactly. So my question is: *how would you make that pure*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure function is one which for any input `x` will always produce the same output `y` and does not change any state. As long as the function does not break those principles, it's a pure function.

Here's an example showcasing the difference between a pure function and some impure functions:

```js
var rect = {
  width: 2,
  height: 4
};

function areaPure(rectangle) {
  return rectangle.width * rectangle.height;
}

function areaImpureMutate(rectangle) {
  rectangle.area = rectangle.width * rectangle.height;
}

function areaImpureOuterState() {
  // Uses variable declared outside of scope
  return rect.width * rect.height;
}

console.log('pure:', areaPure(rect)); // no side effects

// Mutates state
areaImpureMutate(rect);
console.log('mutated:', rect.area);

// Relies on mutable state
rect.height = 5;
console.log('mutable state:', areaImpureOuterState(rect));
rect.width = 5;
console.log('mutable state:', areaImpureOuterState(rect));
```

The hard-and-fast rule for pure functions is that if I give you the same input regardless of the state of the rest of the program, it will *always* give me the same output and *not* mutate the state of the program directly.

So you could rewrite your `test` function like this to make it almost pure:

```
function test(obj) {
    if (obj.order.owner && obj.selectedEvent()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(obj.order.booking_id == '4000' || !obj.isValid(obj.order.order_id) ){
        return false;
    }
    return obj.whatever;
};
```

There's one problem with it: `obj.selectedEvent()` is an impure function which taints this pure function.

Comment: I got the idea, but what's your suggestion of a use case as the one I'm showing?

Comment: @Alvaro See my edit. Keep in mind that if you use impure functions inside of your pure function, it's no longer pure.

Comment: And do you believe it make any sense to do so? Passing objects from here to there just to have a *"pure"* function?

Comment: @Alvaro In many cases, yes. It reduces cognitive load and means you only have to look in one place when something goes wrong. But mutable state is a reality of most programming and is very helpful most of the time. It all depends on your needs but a healthy mixture of both, I think, is the best solution.